# AngularJS: $scope is not updated after function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to update a number in the controller. So I have a controller with this.

```
$scope.someNumber = 5;

$scope.addNumber = function(){
    $scope.someNumber ++;
    console.log($scope.someNumber); // This outputs 6, 7, 8, etc
}
```

Then I show that number, and it works when I refresh the page.

```
<span ng-controller="myController">{{someNumber}}</span>
```

Now I want to call `addNumber()` when I click something. This `div` is inside some code that's being repeated with `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-click="addNumber()">Add +1!</div>
```

The click works because `addNumber()` outputs the correct new number. But for some reason the `span` is not updated with the new value and always shows `5`. I've called `$scope.$apply()` but I get `$apply already in progress error`.

I'm new to Angular, I guess I must be missing something very obvious.

Edit:

I've added the click to the span, and now it is updated.

```
<span ng-controller="myController" ng-click="addNumber()">{{someNumber}}</span>
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Show us more code. Maybe you have an issue with your scope hierarchy.

Comment: Can you show me the result in plunker ?

Comment: Try to use "ng-bind" for someNumber

Comment: Your code probably working for me. did you got any console error?

Comment: I'm not getting any error... and the my code is not much more complicated than this as far as Angular goes.

Comment: Can you add this code in plunkr?

Comment: I've edited my question, sorry I don't have time to use plunkr now. Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Your button (or div) with the `ng-click` property should be inside the controller not outside

Comment: @ChtiwiMalek it's not outside, but the controller directive is on a parent element. Like I said the click works, and the console outputs the correct numbers.

Comment: Just to make Chtiwi Malek comments clear, in your previous config, the controller's scope is the span element. So all the functions and variables are declared in that specific scope and any child scope. Therefore, having the div outside the span element, the div has no access to the scope you created.

Comment: @gsalisi but then if it's a scope accessing problem, why is it that the function `addNumber()` is called and I get the number in the console?

Comment: @Pier I'm looking into that. And i still can't figure out why. There could be some other code in a parent scope that you're accessing.

Comment: Ok, tomorrow I'll post a demo project at plunkr. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Please, add the whole code to the question. A lot of people here have to do guess-work because you didn't. The whole problem could simply be because of this: *This div is inside some code that's being repeated with ng-repeat.*.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you are doing wrong (but not sure since I don't have all your code) is you don't have your controller around your complete html code.

I'm using Angular 1.3 controller as syntax here, this is a bit easier to understand and also the way to go since with the announcement of Angular 2.0 they announced the $scope won't be available anymore. And as you will see in my example I don't use $scope anywhere.

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <p>Hello {{vm.someNumber}}!</p>
    <div ng-click="vm.addNumber()">Add +1!</div>
  </body>
```

And the javascript code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.someNumber = 5;
  vm.addNumber = addNumber;

  function addNumber(){
    vm.someNumber++;
  }
});
```

[See this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oNWoWvIcYQwZMcqpdhJB?p=preview)

Comment: I've tried this, an the console outputs the number correctly, but the span is not updated.

Comment: Which version of AngularJS are you using? Have you tried the Plunker with the example? That one is working for me so the code should be working except if there is some other surrounding problem in your code. Can you provide your complete code in a Plunker for example?

Comment: Latest version 1.3.15

Comment: Hey @CodeBreakers where can I find the documentation for the syntax without `$scope`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
<span>{{someNumber}}</span>
<div ng-click="addNumber()">Add +1!</div>
</div>

$scope.someNumber = 5;

$scope.addNumber = function(){
    $scope.someNumber ++;
    console.log($scope.someNumber); // This outputs 6, 7, 8, etc
}
```

Comment: I've done something similar and it works. Why is it?

Comment: you cannot put ng controller inside span tag and call function outside you need to tell part of html when is inside wich controller         <div ng-controller="example1Ctrl">
            <span>{{someNumber}}</span>
            <div ng-click="funOne()">Add +1!</div>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="example2Ctrl">
            <span>{{someNumber}}</span>
            <div ng-click="Secondfun()">Add +1!</div>
        </div>

Comment: I've moved ng-controller to a parent element with the same result.

Comment: Cool, mine is not. My html with ng-click is inside some other html element.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is working good for my side

Js code

```
 $scope.someNumber = 5;

    $scope.addNumber = function () {
        $scope.someNumber++;
        console.log($scope.someNumber); // This outputs 6, 7, 8, etc
    }
```

html code

```
<span ng-controller="myController">{{someNumber}}
    <div ng-click="addNumber()">Add +1!</div>
    </span>
```

- Your all html code should be using with inside of controller. Just copy and past my code

Comment: It is inside my controller, and the proof is that if I click the div I get the correct number on the console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem was, but I solved it by moving the `ng-controller` directive to a parent html element which contains both the `span` where I want to show the number and the `div`with the `ng-click` directive.

Comment: Somebody said explicitly to move the controller to a parent element?

Like I said I'm new to Angular and I don't know the terminology. I didn't understand what they meant with scope.

Comment: I understand that. Yet, what people were telling you is that you need to have controller-specific code (`addNumber`) *inside* the scope of that controller. In html-terms "as a child of a common parent", not as a sibling. Simply help yourself in the future by posting *all* relevant code inside the quesiton. That said, also take CodeBreakers advice about not using `$scope`. It will be deprecated in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at this I think you've put your update function outside the scope of your controller:

```
<div ng-controller="FooController">{{value}}</div>
<span ng-click="update()"></span>
```

Whereas you need to put the update function within the scope of your controller:

```
<div ng-controller="FooController">{{value}}
    <span ng-click="update()"></span>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!